# Symfony2.3 custom voter via @SecureParam

Tags: security, symfony, annotations

Having writen a custom voter and registered is as a service (first custom voter in project),
Tested it with:

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="product_delete")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function deleteAction(Product $product)
{
    if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted("PRODUCT_DELETE", $product)) {
        throw new \Exception('ACCESS DENIED');
    }
}
```

And it works as expected. However,

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="product_delete")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @SecureParam(name="product", permissions="PRODUCT_DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Product $product)
{
}
```

Regardless of SecureParam annotation, voter recieves a call with following parameters:

```
$attributes = ["ROLE_USER"];
$object instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
```

I'm banging my head against a wall at the moment...

Comment: did you managed to solve this one?

Comment: it was a cache issue with AppKernel.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Symfony2 there is an [access listener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php) (on the kernel.request event) that'll check current security context against the "security.access_control" parameter (usually located in app/config/security.yml).

This listener uses the [access decision manager](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php), which is in charge of delegating to registered voters the object (the request) and the configured roles (the attribute), and then making the decision of granting or denying access. One of these voters is the [RoleVoter](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/RoleVoter.php), which is in charge of saying wether or not the current user has the given role.

This is why your voter is receiving these arguments. It should ignore them though by returning VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN, as it's probably not its purpose to handle them.

I hope I'm clear enough.